# Simple React button test fails

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

Im using jest to test a simple button in React and it keeps failing. My latest iteration complains about render. I'm new to testing and I've been at it for a while and cannot figure this out. What am I missing here?

Here's my **App.js**

```
function clickMe() {
  
  alert("Hello")

}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button id="btn" onClick={clickMe}>Click Me!!</button>

    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Here's my **App.test.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import {render} from 'react-dom'
import App from './App'


test("Click", () => {
  const {container} = render(<App />)

  const button = getByTestId(container, 'btn')
  fireEvent.click(button)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simulate some events with the enzyme library

For this first install this by npm, then import that

```
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';
```

After using this structure to simulate a click on a bottom

Create a wrapper

```
let wrapper = shallow(<App />);
beforeEach( ()=>{
    wrapper = shallow(<CounterApp />);
});
```

This creates a simulation of render components and gives you the capacity to simulate events, this method is working in my project counterApp

```
test('Click', ()=>{

    wrapper.find('button').at(0).simulate('click');
    
    expect(//The action of your botton).toBe(//the result expected);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the same but something like this also worked

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import { configure } from 'enzyme'
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16'
import App from './App'

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })

it('renders the link inside the output area', () => {
  const output = shallow(<App />)
  expect(output.find('div').find('button').length).toEqual(1)
})
```